# Expose configuration items using JSS

Tags: jss

Quiet new to JSS world. We have a requirement to expose the sitecore configuration settings to FE using JSS headless architecture.  On top of this, we have other global data that needs to be exposed to FE e.g. product listings etc.

Given that Layout Service is mainly concerned with route details (place holders, data sources, fields etc), what's the best way to expose the data using JSS headless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have couple of options to expose Sitecore configuration:

1. [Extending Layout Service](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/extending-context-data-returned-by-the-layout-service.html) could be easiest as it's easily accessible to your JSS app. One of the drawbacks of this solution would be performance in long run as it would take some time to run all the extensions and running generating Layout Service response.
2. You can create REST endpoint / API on Back End / usually ASP.NET WebApi project solution/ which will expose this and/or product listing or other information. This can be also easily accessible via your JSS project using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) React library
3. You can also use [Rendering Contents Resolver](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/customizing-the-layout-service-rendering-output.html) - It is something similar to first option but it's adding data to Layout Service output per component where this resolver is set.

[Why to choose third option](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/customizing-the-layout-service-rendering-output.html#why-not-a-separate-rest-endpoint):

- Avoid additional HTTP roundtrip(s).
- Automatically bind the data to the component.
- Make the data available for server/universal rendering.
- Make it easier to query additional data related to the current application, context item (route), or datasource item.

In your case I would choose option 1 or 2 for exposing Sitecore configuration elements. I would go with option 3 for exposing product listing as product listing will be only exposed for components which will have that resolver set

Comment: How about connected graphql @peter

Comment: With 3rd option, given that configuration tree isn't part of route. Are you suggesting to create a config route and add the component that uses custom rendering contents resolver?

Comment: As I have mentioned, I wouldn't expose Sitecore configuration with the 3rd option

Comment: using graphql isn't an option here